# How can I find out what language this file is?

Tags: file

I have [this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kif6wdoq5txebcr/download?dl=1) file, and I have absolutely no idea what kind of file it is.

When I open it in Notepad++ it reads as

```
ð    X      döS
```

**or**

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/d156217b86512943d494f908b74c050e.png))</sub>

How can I figure out what language this is?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not digital pathologists.

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: [Here.](http://patch.us.wizard101.com:12500) @TysonoftheNorthwest

Comment: Looks like the site is broken and giving you a garbage file.  Or the file is supposed to be grabbed by some program that knows what to do with it, probably a game client of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that http://patch.us.wizard101.com:12500/ returns some sort of patch file for a game client.  Chances are there is some api calls you are missing that tell the server what file to generate and return.  But since only game clients need to directly call that file I would delete it and chalk it up to a broken client.

Either that or the site's download handler is broken and is giving a garbage file.

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/supkamlbxro16yy/PatchConfig.xml) is the XML file I found the link in. Lines 4 and 5 I put together to get `patch.us.wizard101.com:12500`. @TysonoftheNorthwest

Answer (score 1):

There's no clear answer, because you can't really. You can do some research on the encoding, or see if you can piece it together depending on the file's origin.

This program will test against common file types to see if it can be opened with success: http://download.cnet.com/TrlD-File-Identifier-for-NET/3000-2248_4-10442461.html